Measurement of PID circuit intrinsic noise
I want to perform a dummy test to compare different general purpose PID circuits. I am specifically interested in the RMS voltage noise of these PID circuits independent of the system they are used to control.
To do that, can I just tee-off the output of each of these PIDs directly and connect one end to their inverting input while the other connects to a scope? Is this a reasonable measurement to compare the precision achieved by different PID circuits? 
